# How to automatically run a command after foregrounding

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, command

Preface: I might be asking the wrong question, so I'll just say what my problem is first.

Whenever I use `^Z` to background vim, then later (can be hours later) run `fg` to bring it back, YouCompleteMe doesn't do any completion (however, it *does* sometimes say below the status line that it needs to be restarted)

A workaround has been to run `:YcmRestartServer` whenever I foreground vim manually, but I'd like to have that run automatically (if it isn't already running).

Comment: I’ll search later, but afaik there are no auto events for this, although presumably source code could be modified to allow it? A SIG event handler for the right thing, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So setting aside that there may be an issue with YCM, you can put the following in your .vimrc.

```
augroup RestartYCM
  autocmd!
  autocmd FocusGained * :YcmRestartServer
augroup END
```

Comment: According to the docs https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#FocusGained the `FocusGained` event only works for GUI

Comment: Maybe. If true, however, I tested it with gvim and it works a treat.

Comment: I'm accepting this, not because it works for every solution, but because it works for GUI, at least, and it was, in fact, a problem with YCM that appears to be patched, so I can't easily test this anymore.

Comment: Great! I actually have a Q for @D._Ben_Knoble, who apparently edited the response to include the (superior) autocommand group. I considered including the autocommand group originally, but did not under the assumption it was not strictly necessary. Would you say that (unless otherwise contraindicated) you would always include groups, or similar "best practices" in responses?